# How to un-pause a FastLoad

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to load data into Teradata via a FastLoad.  During the FastLoad I get an error: ERRLIMIT exceeded and then the FastLoad is Paused.  Of course, when I try to query the error tables, I can't see what errors are happening because the error table is "still being loaded" as the script only paused the FastLoad.

My question is how to I kill the FastLoad, so I can see what errors are being logged and troubleshoot the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a dummy fload job  as following without any content for loading.

   ```
   logon tdpid/username,password;
   begin loading databasename.tablename;
   /*  emtpy loading   to release fastload lock */
   end loading;
   logoff;
   ```
2. If above didnt work you might need to drop table